# while loop won't stop even condition evaluates to false

Tags: javascript, while-loop, command-prompt

```
let checkOrFold = undefined
while(checkOrFold != 'check' && checkOrFold != 'fold'){
    let checkOrFold = prompt(`check or fold?`);
    console.log(checkOrFold != 'check' && checkOrFold != 'fold')
}
console.log('finish') here
```

even the console is logging false but prompt keeps popping up. What could be wrong?

Tried debugging. When 'check' or 'fold' is typed, console.log should show finish.

Comment: remove the 'let' keyword inside the while loop, you are creating another variable. Just use 'checkOrFold' inside the loop without creating a new one.

Answer (score 1):

You’re declaring another variable with the same name in the while loop. Remove the `let` from within the while loop and you should get what you’re looking for.

```
let checkOrFold = undefined;
while(checkOrFold != 'check' && checkOrFold != 'fold'){
    checkOrFold = prompt(`check or fold?`);
    console.log(checkOrFold != 'check' && checkOrFold != 'fold');
}
console.log('finish');
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to prompt outside the while loop once, so `checkOrFold` has a chance to receive an input. You also, by  accident, setup a separate block scoped variable `checkOrFold` inside the loop, you need to use the same `checkOrFold` for the whole portion of code to work.

Solution:

```js
let checkOrFold = undefined;

checkOrFold = prompt(`check or fold?`);
while(checkOrFold != 'check' && checkOrFold != 'fold'){
    checkOrFold = prompt(`check or fold?`);
    console.log(checkOrFold != 'check' && checkOrFold != 'fold')
}
console.log('finish')
```

Answer (score 0):

try matching the response till you get either check or fold as a response
while(checkOrFold = 'check' || checkOrFold = 'fold')